# Is it normal that programs don't have title bar and borders in Ubuntu with Gnome3?

Tags: gnome, 13.10

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy Salamander, then I installed Gnome 3 (gnome-shell).

I found a little bit strange that almost all windows doesn't a title bar or border, however they have a close button. Is that normal?

**Folders & Files**

[image: a window on Ubuntu 13.10 with Gnome 3]

**System Monitor**

[image: a window on Ubuntu 13.10 with Gnome 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a picture found on [the GNOME website](http://www.gnome.org/gnome-3/) on 5 nov 2013 00:57 UTC.

As you can see, the layout is the same.

So, yes, IMHO this is normal GNOME 3 behavior.

[image: gnome3]